# Pass custom class instance between activities

Tags: android, android-intent, serialization, parcelable

I have a custom class 'Game' which i init at top of activity code. I then go to another activity, usually i pass arraylists etc but i want to move to passing my custom class.....

My custom class 'game' is a bunch of strings and arraylists with getter and setter mehtods.

i get a

> Game is not a parcelable or serializable object

error when I try to add it to the intent. Any ideas what i can do here?

```
//Init Instance of Game class
Game newGame = new Game();
```

Set my listener. It works for

```
//Setup onclick listeners
text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this_Activity.this, next_Activity.class);
        i.putExtra("players", myList);
        i.putExtra("newGame", (Parcelable) newGame);
        startActivityForResult(i, 0);
    }
});
```

Comment: This one might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29166753/passing-parcelable-object-between-intents?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also, your class `Game` may to implement interface `Serializable`:

```
public class Game implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

You have to change listener in first activity:

```
text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this_Activity.this, next_Activity.class);
        i.putExtra("players", myList);
        i.putExtra("newGame", newGame);
        startActivityForResult(i, 0);
    }
});
```

And change method `onCreate` in `next_Activity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Game newGame = (Game) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("newGame");
}
```

Comment: This is a fantastic, comprehensive and succinct answer. Thank you Arthur.

Answer (score 1):

Game class need to implement Parcelable.

Comment: Thx for response. Can you expand on your answer.

Comment: Refer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html There you can see that the class MyParcelable is implementing  Parcelable.

Comment: Also refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550670/benefit-of-using-parcelable-instead-of-serializing-object to understand why Parcelable is more preferred than Serializable